# How to add a static unit (text) to a TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I currently have this `TextFormField` with a hintText:

[image: Current TextFormField]

the goal is to add Units inside the TextFormField, regardless of whether the user is typing or not. It should kinda look like this:

[image: goal]

How to achieve this?
Also, how to center the value?

Here's my current code for the TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: '0.0',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white24,
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
    ),
    counterText: '',
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The`TextFormField` decoration can a `suffixText` property

```dart
     TextFormField(
       controller: c,
       // align to center
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       decoration:  InputDecoration(
         hintText: '0.0',
         // show kg
         suffixText: 'Kg',
     )
```

Text can be centered using the `textAlign` property

Comment: Thanks, it worked except that it is only shown when typing, is there a way to show the suffix all the time?

Comment: There's an open issue as of now. 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64552

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use TextFormField and text inside row which is inside a container
something like this can help

```
Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [TextFormField(), Text('Kg')],
          ),
        ),
```

another way is that you can use

```
TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(suffixText: 'Kg'),
              ),
```

but here the problem is that you will only get suffix text when the TextFormField is enabled, one workaround you can try to make it always visible is to use `autovalidate` property like

```
TextFormField(
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                decoration: InputDecoration(suffixText: 'Kg'),
              ),
```

I have not tested this autovalidateMode but it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks but AutovalidateMode doesn't bring focus so the suffix stays hidden, it's no problem though :). The Problem with the first method you suggested is that the Text would be outside of the TextFormField, but I could wrap the Row with a BoxDecoration, thanks for leading the way :D

Comment: yeah you can use the decoration property of Container() to add a boxDecoration instead with that you can also fix the size of the container altogether, anyways your welcome, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 