# How to show a text along textfield data like this in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, mobile-development

[image: Flutter textfield]

How to show a constant text in textfield in Flutter along with typed data like in this picture.

Comment: Please elaborate the question little more and share code if you try something yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String Interpolation`. Using `$` to access variable in Text Widget.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double quantity = 1;
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.production_quantity_limits_outlined),
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Text("$quantity (qty)"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is a textfield, then what can be done?

Comment: You can use `suffix` in Textfield to show (qty)

Comment: can it shown next to textfield value?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947031/how-to-add-a-static-unit-text-to-a-textformfield-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Example extends StatelessWidget {
 const Example({super.key});
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   double quantity = 1;
   return TextField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       label: Text("$quantity (qty)"),
       border: OutlineInputBorder()
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: The label shows on the textfield border.

Comment: then use hintText

Comment: play with TextField bro

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like this:**

```
class TextFieldExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController? controller;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            filled: true,
            hintText: '1(qty)',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.watch),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not hint text, its more like suffix but close to textfield value.

Comment: but this working fine